# The equality case of the Schwartz inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Question:

The fact that $a^2 \geq 0$ $ \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$; elementary as it may seem, is
nevertheless the fundamental idea upon which most important inequalities
are ultimately based. The great-granddaddy of all inequalities is the
Schwarz inequality: $ x_1 y_1 + x_2 y_2 \leq \sqrt {x_1^2 + x_2^2} $ $\sqrt {y_1^2 + y_2^2} $

1. Prove that if $x_1 = \lambda y_1 $ and $x_2 = \lambda y_2$ for some number $\lambda$ then equality holds in the Schwarz inequality.

Easy you get $ \lambda (y_1^2 + y_2^2) \geq |\lambda | (y_1^2 + y_2^2) $
if we define $ y_1 \geq x_1 $ and $ y_2 >x_2 $ w.o loss of generality both side are equal.

2. Prove the same thing when $ y_1 = y_2 = 0$

you just get 0=0 which is fine.

3. Now assume that $y_1 $ and $y_2$ are not both $0$ and that there is no such $\lambda $ such that $x_1 = \lambda y_1 $ and $x_2 = \lambda y_2$

Then $ 0 < ( \lambda y_1- x_1)^2 + ( \lambda y_2- x_2)^2 $

How to finish the answer to this part is my question and honestly I have no idea what that last line says/implies and intuitively it looks like gibberish so please dumb down your answer please!

Edit: ( sorry about getting the sign backwards really tired when i wrote this out.) I expanded it $ 0 <  \lambda^2 (y_1^2 + y_2^2) -2\lambda ( x_1 y_1 +  x_2 y_2)  + (x_1^2 + x_2^2)$ not sure if that helps anyone.

Comment: The direction should be reversed $x_1 y_1 + x_2 y_2 \le \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}\sqrt{y_1^2 + y_2^2}$

Comment: $0 < ( \lambda y_1- x_1)^2 + ( \lambda y_2- x_2)^2$ is a quadratic in $\lambda$ and positive ! What's the discriminant of this quadratic ? :)

Comment: "the great-granddaddy of all inequalities" is the triangle inequality imho

Comment: @GFauxPas In college I took an entire course on inequalities and the author of the book seemed to think it was the arithmetic/geometric mean inequality. I believe the name of the textbook was "inequalities"; try searching for that on amazon and see what you get.

Comment: @GFauxPas Oh sure, NOW when you search for "inequalities" on Amazon the math book comes up. Maybe it's relying on my search history though. I've bought a lot of math books.

Comment: @MattSamuel There's more than one book with that title; I'd appreciate it if you have a particular author to recommend

Comment: @GFauxPas Apparently it was more than one author, and foolish and young as I was at the time I didn't realize how famous they were.  by G. H. Hardy (Author), J. E. Littlewood (Author), G. Pólya (Author)

Comment: @r9m i don't actually know what a discriminant is, got any recommendations book wise.

Comment: @Faust7 A book that has the Schwarz-Inequality and the discriminant ? :) [Higher algebra by Barnard and Child](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Higher_algebra.html?id=3-I5AAAAMAAJ) is a good book imho :)

Comment: @r9m 11$ from Amazon hell yeah i bought it =)

Comment: @Faust7 Its a good book to keep with yourself ! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proving Cauchy-Schwarz inequality question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64474/proving-cauchy-schwarz-inequality-question)

Comment: The answer defiantly looks the same as what my question is leading to but i defiantly haven't learned what a discriminate is; is there anther way to prove it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19603/discussion-between-r9m-and-faust7).

Comment: Probably the book was "The Cauchy-Schwarz hy-schwarz master class".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you obtained,$$0 < ( \lambda y_1- x_1)^2 + ( \lambda y_2- x_2)^2 \iff (y_1^2+y_2)^2\lambda^2-2(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)\lambda+(x_1^2+x_2^2) > 0$$

Now if you are not familiar with using the discriminant, you can "complete the square" to get:
$$\iff (y_1^2+y_2^2)\left(\color{red}{\lambda - \frac{x_1y_1+x_2y_2}{y_1^2+y_2^2}} \right)^2+\color{blue}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)-\frac{(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)^2}{(y_1^2+y_2^2)}} > 0$$

As this must be true for all $\lambda$, in particular it must hold for $\color{red}{\lambda = \dfrac{x_1y_1+x_2y_2}{y_1^2+y_2^2}} $, from which the desired inequality follows.
$$\implies \color{blue}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)-\frac{(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)^2}{(y_1^2+y_2^2)}} > 0 \implies (x_1^2+x_2^2)(y_1^2+y_2^2)> (x_1y_1+x_2y_2)^2$$